# jqGrid Fixed width table when hide show column

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free jqGrid, 2015-10-08.When the show and hide the column many times the size of the table is constantly increasing. How to fixed the width of the table.
I used free jqGrid in main project.
example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12340/)

```
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    maxRowNum: 200,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used "free-jqgrid" tag in your question, but the jqFiddle demo, which you included used old jqGrid 4.6. Free jqGrid can be loaded from GitHub [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), be used from CDN using the URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or be used from WebJars or be installed from `npm` (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid)) or `bower` (see [here](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid)) or from NuGet (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid)). **Free jqGrid** is the fork of jqGrid which I develop short after renaming jqGrid to **Guriddo jqGrid JS** (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and changing the licence agreements. Even if the source code is still available on GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid)) it can't be used for free. See [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) the prices of Guriddo jqGrid JS.

**If you would use free jqGrid** 4.11.1 or the current source from the demo then **no constantly increasing of the width of grid will be exist**. See the modified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12341/. I recommend you additionally to comment the line

```js
width: 300,
```

in the demo and retry the test. You will see a little another behavior by hiding/showing columns.

Comment: Oleg, but when we add height: 100 this problem appears again. Haw fix this http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12349/ .need fixed height!

Comment: @diJey: Then you will have the grid which has `height: 100`. Sorry, but if you have a question or if you found a problem you should clear describe it.

Comment: I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free jqGrid, 2015-10-08. When the show and hide the column many times the size of the table is constantly increasing

Comment: @diJey: 1) You should use the latest 4.11.1 or the last code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). 2) you should provide the demo, which reproduce the problem.

Comment: I add 4.11.1 in demo.Click Show to hide several times. This: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12350/.

Comment: @diJey: I'm not sure how you created your demo, but if I replace `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` to `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or if I create **the same** demo myself even using `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` from jsDelivr CDN http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12351/ or from cdnjs http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12352/ then I an't reproduce the problem. To be able to debug the code I have to have the demo which uses non-minimized code. You should better use `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` - it's the current code which I can fix it I'll find some bug.

Comment: @diJey: You are welcome! The usage of `$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 300);` *after* `showCol` and `hideCol` will work, but all should work **without the setting** if you use fixed `width` option (like `width: 300`) *during creating the grid*. You would would find some problem you can post bug report, but it should include the demo with the test case (step by step instructions to reproduce the problem). The demo should use `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js`. After I'll post the fix to GitHub, the same demo should work correctly.

Comment: I found a problem. The fact is that when a lot of records, and a scroll bar, that's when the problem starts! Олег у меня проблемы с английским. Напишу на русском, чтобы было понятнее. Проблема появляется тогда, когда появляется вертикальный скролбар! Позже напишу пример

Comment: @diJey: OK, I understand Russian better as English, it could be only the problem for other readers. Could you provide the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12352/ or http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12356/ (the same, but using `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` from GitHub) have vertical scroll bar, but I can't reproduce any problem. Could you provide the demo with exact test case (step by step instruction to reproduce the problem)? If I can debug the code then I can see the place which I need fix. You can write me in Russian if it's easier for you.

Comment: Начнем сначала. Меня запутало, что jsFiddle каким то образом даже при полной перезагрузке страницы отображает не актуальные данные, а отображает те данные, когда была нажата Run. Я взял другой браузер и полностью очистил кэш и куки. Далее я первым делом запустил пример: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yNw3C/12341/   Этот пример не работает корректно в том случае, когда у нас много записей и появляется вертикальная прокрутка.

Comment: Далее второй пример и все остальные примеры одинаковые (отличия только в репозиториях jqGrid). В них работает все корректно, т.к. добавлено  $("#grid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 300);

Comment: Т.е. у меня если в любой из примеров я удаляю $("#grid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 300); ни один из примеров не работает корректно!

Comment: Вот тут удалил из последнего примера строки с  $("#grid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 300); http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12359/  И чтобы мы могли увидеть как работает. Желательно после загрузки fiddle нажать кнопку Run

Comment: @diJey: Спасибо! Я действительно добавил строку `$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 300);` и забыл об этом, так как постоянно отвлекался на другие дела. Я могу воспроиздести проблему. Мне нужно сейчас сделать другие важные дела, а после я подправлю код free jqGrid, опубликую на GitHub и сообщу через новый комментарий.

Comment: @diJey: I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/e1ea3a3ebc833ea5c8ddbdcffa51daec3d0409a5), which should resolve the problem. I plan to make some additional changes to fix other minor problems, but there concerned rounding and can change the width to 1-2px only. It's not so important like the problem, which you reported. Thank you once more for it.